# golang - tcpclient when I send http request, it always return (bad request 400)

Tags: go, ssl, tcp, httprequest, tcpclient

I am trying to send an HTTP request through a TCP/TLS socket in GOLang, but when I try to send it, no matter what the host is, it always returns (bad request 400), so I think it must be something wrong with the way I use to send a request by TCP/TLS, I searched, and I looked for an way to do what I want to do, but no results:

```
package main

import (
"crypto/rand"
"crypto/tls"
"fmt"
"net"
"strings"
)

func main() {

headers := make(map[string]string)

headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
request := parseRequest("httpbin.org", "/get", "get", headers, nil, "")
println(request)

tcpConn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "httpbin.org:443")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
cf := &tls.Config{Rand: rand.Reader, InsecureSkipVerify: true}
ssl := tls.Client(tcpConn, cf)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer ssl.Close()

n, err := ssl.Write([]byte(request))

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(n, err)
    return
}

buf := make([]byte, 1024)
n, err = ssl.Read(buf)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(n, err)
    return
}

println(string(buf[:n]))

}

func parseRequest(host string, path string, method string, headers map[string]string, data map[string]string, rawData string) string {

method = strings.ToUpper(method)
rawRequest := fmt.Sprintf(`%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n`, strings.ToUpper(method), path)

if method == `GET` && (data != nil || rawData != ``) {
    var rawQuery string
    if rawData != `` {
        rawQuery = rawData
    } else {
        i := 0
        for key, value := range data {
            if i == len(data)-1 {
                rawQuery += fmt.Sprintf(`%s=%s`, key, value)
            } else {
                rawQuery += fmt.Sprintf(`%s=%s&`, key, value)
            }
            i++
        }
    }
    query := fmt.Sprintf(`%s?%s`, path, rawQuery)
    rawRequest = fmt.Sprintf(`%s %s HTTP/1.1\r\n`, strings.ToUpper(method), query)
}

var rawHeaders string
for key, value := range headers {
    rawHeaders += fmt.Sprintf(`%s: %s\r\n`, key, value)
}

if !strings.Contains(strings.ToLower(rawHeaders), `host`) {
    rawRequest += fmt.Sprintf(`Host: %s\r\n`, host)
}
rawRequest += fmt.Sprintf(`%s\r\n`, rawHeaders)

if method == `POST` && (data != nil || rawData != ``) {

    if rawData != `` {
        rawRequest += rawData
    } else {
        i := 0
        for key, value := range data {
            if i == len(data)-1 {
                rawRequest += fmt.Sprintf(`%s=%s`, key, value)
            } else {
                rawRequest += fmt.Sprintf(`%s=%s&`, key, value)
            }
            i++
        }
    }

}

return rawRequest
}
```

Comment: Use interpreted [string literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) instead of raw string literals so that `\r\n` is interpreted as the bytes  [13, 10].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Go, Back quote `` ` `` is used to denote a raw string, as per [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals):

> Raw string literals are character sequences between back quotes, as in
> `foo`. Within the quotes, any character may appear except back quote.
> The value of a raw string literal is the string composed of the
> uninterpreted (implicitly UTF-8-encoded) characters between the
> quotes; in particular, backslashes have no special meaning and the
> string may contain newlines. Carriage return characters ('\r') inside
> raw string literals are discarded from the raw string value.

That means, all `\r\n` in your code is not interpreted as carriage returns or line breaks. You should change to use double quote `"`.

And as a general style guideline, one should use double quote unless there is need for a lot of escaping.